# Join procedures only once on Firebird

Tags: join, stored-procedures, firebird

I'm trying to left join two stored procedures in a Firebird query.
In my example data the first returns 70 records, the second just 1 record.

```
select
    --...
from MYSP1('ABC', 123) s1
    left join MYSP2('DEF', 456) s2
         on s1.FIELDA = s2.FIELDA
        and s1.FIELDB = s2.FIELDB
```

The problem is performances: it takes 10 seconds, while each procedure takes less than 1 second. I suspect that procedures are run multiple times instead of just once. It would make sense to execute them just once, because I pass fixed parameters to them.

**Is there a way to oblige Firebird to simply execute once each procedure and then join their results?**

Comment: AFAIK, no, although you could try to join two sub-selects from those stored procedures. Don't have time to test if that actually works though.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thanks, I tried your suggestion but it doesn't improve performances.

Comment: Then I'm afraid there is no way; joining to a stored procedure behaves like a lateral join (it is evaluated for each row in the driving 'table').

Comment: are those `FIELDA` and `FIELDB` arbitrary generated data or are they a subset taken from some dictionary table?

Comment: @Arioch'The they are just example fields returned from the SPs. Names are arbitrary.

Comment: Sad. Otherwise you could join both SP's with the source dictionary table

Comment: Or maybe u misunderstood me? I asked about values source not about column names

Comment: @Arioch'The ok :) now I got it... data from the SPs are arbitrary, there's no dictionary table... thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems there is no way, I solved this issue running this query inside a new stored procedure, where I cache all results from `MYSP2` into a global temporary table and make the join between `MYSP1` and the temporary table.

This is temporary table definition:

```
create global temporary table MY_TEMP_TABLE
(
    FIELDA varchar(3) not null,
    FIELDB smallint not null,
    FIELDC varchar(10) not null
 );
```

This is stored procedure body:

```
--cache MYSP2 results
delete from MY_TEMP_TABLE;
insert into MY_TEMP_TABLE
    select *
    from MYSP2('DEF', 456)
    ;

--join data
for
select
    --...
from MYSP1('ABC', 123) s1
    left join MY_TEMP_TABLE s2
         on s1.FIELDA = s2.FIELDA
        and s1.FIELDB = s2.FIELDB
into
    --...
do
    suspend;
```

But if there is another solution without temporary tables it would be great!

Comment: Frankly, I would populate the table with results from both SPs (using `MERGE`) and then selected from GTT for the output. This way you would be able to do without a persistent SP (first part being sent as `EXECUTE BLOCK`) if needed. Also, please specify that the GTT is per-transaction not per-connection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
with MYSP2W as (MYSP2('DEF', 456))
select
    --...
from MYSP1('ABC', 123) s1
    left join MYSP2W s2
    on s1.FIELDA = s2.FIELDA
    and s1.FIELDB = s2.FIELDB
```

Comment: thanks, but this query cannot run. Anyway I tried using a WITH clause to enclose one of the procedures, but nothing changes.